# Node JS - Big Query insert to a Struct data type

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-bigquery

Supposed I have a field "student" with a record type how or what should be the format of my json object if I would insert into a field with a record/struct type.

Would it be something like this?

```
{
student: {
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 23
  }
}
```

according here https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/samples/insertRowsAsStream.js I would pass an object or array of objects to insert something to big query but I can't find an example that inserts into a record type

Answer (score 2):

From the look at the repo, remove the student part, use student as the table name instead.

So it's just the object of student, or array of student objects.

Record type = table or even dataset.

Comment: But what if my table that contains the student fields also contains other fields that are not record type? Should I create another insert for that?

Comment: @Ian Santos, you have the option to do it however you wish, that's one of the benefits of NOSQL solutions, it's not relational, so you *could* have an array of projects on each student record, or have seperate record types/tables for both. Entirely up to you, Id consider the simplicity of the first approach, keep in mind that the more projects a user has the slower operations may become for the first approach (NOSQL in general, probably not BigQuery).

Answer (score 1):

You can insert RECORD type fields by enclosing their subfields with curly brackets `{}`, just like in your example.

In order to insert REPEATED fields, you would have to enclose them within square brackets `[]`.

I hope this answers your question!